# Uploading large files to S3 with ruby (aws:s3) - connection reset by peer on UBUNTU

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, amazon-s3

I am trying to store some large files on S3 using ruby [aws:s3](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/) using:

```
S3Object.store("video.mp4", open(file), 'bucket', :access => :public_read)
```

For files of 100 MB or so everything is great but with files of over 200 MB I get a "Connection reset by peer" error in the log.

Has anyone come across this weirdness?  From the web, it seems to be an issue with large but I have not yet come across a definitive solution.

I am using Ubuntu.

## EDIT:

This seems to be a Linux issue as suggested [here](http://scie.nti.st/2008/3/14/amazon-s3-and-connection-reset-by-peer).

Answer (score 0):

No idea where the original problem might be, but as workaround you could try multipart upload.

```
filename = "video.mp4"
min_chunk_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024  # S3 minimum chunk size (5Mb)
    @object.multipart_upload do |upload|
      io = File.open(filename)

      parts = []

      bufsize = (io.size > 2 * min_chunk_size) ? min_chunk_size : io.size
      while buf = io.read(bufsize)
        md5 = Digest::MD5.base64digest(buf)

        part = upload.add_part(buf)
        parts << part

        if (io.size - (io.pos + bufsize)) < bufsize
          bufsize = (io.size - io.pos) if (io.size - io.pos) > 0
        end
      end

      upload.complete(parts)
    end
```

S3 multipart upload is little tricky as each part size must be over 5Mb, but that has been taken care of above code.